# how to convert this MsSQL query into postgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

```
createDB @"if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = '{0}') create DATABASE [{0}]" -------- 

createLogin @"if not Exists (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals 
     WHERE name = '{0}') BEGIN CREATE LOGIN [{0}] FROM WINDOWS END"
```

How to convert this to Postgres?

Comment: What does the code do?

Comment: Not possible, PostgreSQL doesn't have access to the Windows-users on OS-level